# Rails - find_by_sql - Querying with multiple values for one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble joining the values for querying multiple values to one column. Here's what I got so far:

```
def self.showcars(cars)
    to_query = []
    if !cars.empty? 
      to_query.push cars
    end
    return self.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car IN ( ? )"])
end
```

That makes the query into:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car IN (--- \n- \"honda\"\n- \"toyota\"\n')
```

It seems find_by_sql sql_injection protection adds the extra characters. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need `find_by_sql`? Since you're performing a `SELECT *`, and assuming your method resides on the `Car` model, a better way would be:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.showcars(*cars)
    where('car in :cars', :cars => cars)
    # or
    where(:car => cars)
  end
end
```

Note the `*` right after the parameter name... Use it and you won't need to write code to make a single parameter into an array.

If you really need `find_by_sql`, try to write it this way:

```
def self.showcars(*cars)
  find_by_sql(['SELECT * FROM cars where car in (?)', cars])
end
```

Comment: Yes, I'm joining legacy databases in my actual query so I went with find_by_sql. Anyway to make this work?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you a `find_by_sql` alternative. Check it out.

Comment: Looks like I didn't even need to do any joining of passed values since they were already arrays. This is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the to_query array into a comma separated string with all values in single quotes, and then passing this string as a parameter "?".

Comment: I've tried joining with comma separated and it does this - ('honda\', \'toyota'). Again seems like the sql injection is kicking in which will result with zero records because honda\ does not exist. There's gotta be a way to do this. Someone must have experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolve.

```
def self.average_time(time_init, time_end)

    query = <<-SQL
                 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crawler_twitters AS twitter WHERE CAST(twitter.publish AS TIME) BETWEEN '#{time_init}' AND '#{time_end}'
                  GROUP BY user) AS total_tweets_time;
    SQL

    self.find_by_sql(sanitize_sql(query))
  end
```